# Return MatplotLib Image from flask service | Does not work with rich format

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I have created an Python application hosted on Flask and publishing some images, it is working fine when I publishing a normal plot using axis.plot functionality but when I want to add rich text, better formatting etc then it is not rendering any image, here the sample reproducible code

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, Response, make_response
from flask_restful  import Resource, Api
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import numpy as np
import json
import random
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.debug = True

class Graph(Resource):
    def get(self):
        fig = Figure()
        axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

        xs = range(100)
        ys = [random.randint(1, 50) for x in xs]

        axis.plot(xs, ys)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        output = BytesIO()
        canvas.print_png(output)
        response = make_response(output.getvalue())
        response.mimetype = 'image/png'
        return response

class PltGraph(Resource):
    def get(self):

        fig = Figure()
        xs = range(100)
        ys = [random.randint(1, 50) for x in xs]
        plt.plot(xs,ys)
        plt.ylabel("Y label")
        plt.xlabel("X label")
        plt.title("x and y")
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        output = BytesIO()
        canvas.print_png(output)
        response = make_response(output.getvalue())
        response.mimetype = 'image/png'
        print(response)
        return response


api.add_resource(Graph,'/Graph.png')
api.add_resource(PltGraph,'/PltGraph.png')

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 81)
```

Here the first method 'graph.png' gives result [image]

But the second method 'PtgGraph.png' gives blank result, please help

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of analysis, I found that define a figure i.e. ***plt.figure(1)*** and passing that figure in figure canvas once plot functionality end will produce same result i.e.
***canvas = FigureCanvas(plt.figure(1))***

```
class PltGraph(Resource):
    def get(self):
        fig = Figure()
        xs = range(100)
        ys = [random.randint(1, 50) for x in xs]
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(xs,ys)
        plt.ylabel("Y label")
        plt.xlabel("X label")
        plt.title("x and y")
        canvas = FigureCanvas(plt.figure(1)) 
        output = BytesIO()
        canvas.print_png(output)
        response = make_response(output.getvalue())
        response.mimetype = 'image/png'
#        print(response)
        return response
```